# RFC: Proof relating area to intersection of points.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

this is the first time I used latex. Please excuse the rough edges.

I asked a question about this problem here: [Relating area to a line intersecting with a point.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/885175/relating-area-to-a-line-intersecting-with-a-point)
but I think I was able to find a reasonable solution, so this question is more about whether my reasoning would work and perhaps how to have better polish on particular points.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: So what is exactly your question?